# Setting custom picture control in Nikon D3100 DSLR?

Tags: nikon, digital, image-quality, nikon-d3100

How to create custom picture control in Nikon d3100 dslr's? I have tried with my Nikon 3100 without success, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the **MENU** button, select **Set Picture Control**, and press the **>** button. This displays a list of the default picture controls. Select one as a basis and press **>** to show modification options.

See page 95 of the manual that came with your camera (ahem) for more details.

Comment: yes i checked the instruction manual. It is in 95th page. Thanks guys..

Comment: But we can only modify picture control and save in existing controls sets.Dint find a option to create a new picture control as in d5100 model..

Comment: Evidently a limitation of the cheaper model...